# Find groups in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Is there any algorithm that allows me to make groups in a graph? When I write about the *group*, I mean graph nodes in the group: a parent-node, and child-nodes. There must be one parent and at least one child in such a group. Groups are marked in yellow in the figure. 
I present two graphs with that groups. Graph nodes are in the groups only if they are closest to the *outer* part of the graph. Nodes in the middle of the graph are not important to me.

Is there any algorithm to solve that problem? Or do you know a graph problem that is near to my?

[image: Groups]

Answer (score 1):

I think if a node has only one edge, it will be a node of a *group*.

So first, find all nodes which has only one edge. And group the node with its neighbor node. It would be a *group* you want to find.

Finally, if there an intersection between two *groups*, combine the *groups* and make one *group* recursively.

Comment: For grouping, maybe use a `map<node, list<node>>`, like `for leaf in graph.leafs: group[next_node].add(leaf)`

Comment: Your definition of "group" is terribly imprecise. If you make it precise, you'll be half way to an algorithm.

Comment: @Gene The question says `Graph nodes are in the groups only if they are closest to the outer part of the graph.`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a graph and you need to split it into several groups by yourself or by specific query you can use [DSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)  algorithm by adding the chosen nodes to specific parent so that you'll build several components(groups).